# Pressing enter works on all other browsers except internet explorer

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I have following code in my `default.aspx` page

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <div class="default">
        <div class="search_panel">

        <select id="Select1"  name="search_type">
            <option>option1</option>
            <option>option2</option>
        </select><input name="search_text"  type="text" /><input name="search"  formaction="page.aspx" type="image" alt="submit"  src="images/search.jpg" />

            </div>
       </div>
</asp:Content>
```

When the user presses `enter` the search button works on every browser (firefox, chrome, safari) but not in IE 8. Why is that happening?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `DefaultButton` property on the [Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlform.defaultbutton%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or a [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton.aspx) control.

Example:

```
<form id="Form1"
        defaultbutton="search"
        runat="server">
```

Or

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
  <asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="search">
    <div class="default">
        <div class="search_panel">
          <select id="Select1"  name="search_type">
            <option>option1</option>
            <option>option2</option>
          </select>
          <input name="search_text" type="text" />
          <input name="search" id="search" formaction="page.aspx" type="image" alt="submit"  src="images/search.jpg" />
        </div>
     </div>
   </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: it showing the following error



The DefaultButton of 'Panel1' must be the ID of a control of type IButtonControl

Comment: @jonnydepp If possible change the search button to an asp [image button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton(v=vs.110).aspx)  control instead.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in the HTML standard that dictates that <kbd>enter</kbd> should submit a form. It's not really a bug that IE 8 does not submit the form; the other browsers are just good at guessing what enter should do.

Just to be safe, you should *explicitly* add code to have the enter key submit the form.

Comment: Add JavaScript for the `keypress` event, either on your `input` if you just want the enter key to submit when it's focused, or on the document if you want the enter key to always submit.

Comment: Or just do what Magnus posted; looks like ASP.NET will automatically emit this JavaScript when you use the `DefaultButton` property.